# O365, I have a Column Named 'Status' to show Green/Red circle but I am struggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, js

This is from a List and on List setting there are two Columns that involves the problem I am facing.

- Status (absolute name = ColorStatus)
- NewCol2

Users will enter in either 0 or 1 in NewCol2 field and in List settings,

Status has a formula of =NewCol2 so that it stores the number (0 or 1).

This is the code I tried to display the green (1) / red light (0)

```
///

(function () {
    var ColorStatusFieldCtx = {};

    // Define template variable  
    ColorStatusFieldCtx.Templates = {};

    // Define your required fields and functions to call in each case.
    // In our case the field is Progress
    // Override Function is PatientColorStatusViewTemplate
    ColorStatusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "ColorStatus": {"View": ColorStatusViewTemplate}
      //"Movie":{"View": StatesViewTemplate}


    };

    // Register the template override with SP2013 
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(
    ColorStatusFieldCtx
    );

})();



// Override Progress Level field with color based on conditional value
function ColorStatusViewTemplate(ctx) {

    var _StatusValue = ctx.CurrentItem.Status;
    //var _movieValue = ctx.CurrentItem.Movie;

     if (_StatusValue == "1")
     {
        return "<img src='/sites/CC/SiteAssets/Greendotdot.png'/>";
     }

     if (_StatusValue == '0')
     {
        return "<img src='/sites/CC/SiteAssets/reddotdot.png'/>";
     }  

}


///////////////
```

I've tried many things and one time I got the Greendot to work but it made even '0's Green too. After tweaking a little, I lost it and I cannot even get the Green to work.

It does not have to replace it with image, if you could provide me the code to replace it with  . <-- a dot with 30px and green, I would be super happy too!!!

If it is easier to do it on JSON (conditional formatting) I guess that works too!!

I've been JS Linking to the List.

Please help me.... T_T

Comment: is the image URL resolving? No 404s in Dev console? Try returning this as a test return "<div style='background-color:red' >" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "</a>";

Comment: @Colbs Okay! I will give it a shot!

Comment: @Colbs I just tried it but still nothing happened. On the Status column, I still see 1's and 0's.

Comment: in Chrome, press F12, then ctrl + P, then search for your .js and add a breakpoint. Are you sure it's hitting that code? Try removing the if statement. Also, might need to change the field type to string

Comment: @Colbs I tried it, and I think it isn't hitting the code. I wasn't able to find the JS file that is Linked to the List webpart. However, I was clicking things and I clicked on 'Modify View' -> 'Style' -> Basic Table. It somehow worked...

Comment: nice troubleshooting

Comment: @colbs I am wondering why it did the magic though

Comment: Is the "Minimal Download Strategy" feature enabled for that site?

Comment: are you using classic view or modern view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the Green/Red circle in your Status column, you don't need to use JSLink as this column itself is a calculated column.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to List settings and create "Status" as calculated field.
2. Use below formula for this calculated field:

   `="<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&IF([NewCol2]==1,"Green",IF([NewCol2]==0,"Red","Yellow"))&";'>•</DIV>"`
3. Choose Number(1,1.0,100) for the return data type of field.
4. Use below image for reference.

[image]

Comment: If you are using modern view then you can also use the column formatting using JSON.

Comment: Welcome. If this answer helped you please upvote and accept it so that others can get help from it.

Comment: Yes! I did upvote and accept but since I have less than 15 reputations, it's not taking my upvote.....

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
var _StatusValue = ctx.CurrentItem.Status;
```

to

```
var _StatusValue = ctx.CurrentItem.ColorStatus;
```

Comment: It did not work - there was no change to the list T_T..  @Damjan Tomic